# What are the details for using CF_SQL_NVARCHAR in ColdFusion 10?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

The ColdFusion 10 documentation on Updating Your Database has a section on [Database-related enhancements in ColdFusion 10](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e02b-7ff3.html#WSe61e35da8d318518-9efe7cf1358680a71d-8000).  That page mentions that there is now support for `CF_SQL_NVARCHAR` among others, but with no details about them.  Additionally, the [cfqueryparam documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html) hasn't been updated to include their existence.

The [ColdFusion 9 documentation for cfqueryparam](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html) mentions that `CF_SQL_VARCHAR` maps to `varchar` in MSSQL.  This is true unless the ColdFusion Administrator [datasource settings](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fe5.html) has the `String Format` setting enabled.  In which case `CF_SQL_VARCHAR` maps to `nvarchar`.  This poorly documented feature is a hack which can [cause performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543755/slow-query-with-cfqueryparam-searching-on-indexed-column-containing-hashes) within ColdFusion.

So it's great that they have introduced `CF_SQL_NVARCHAR`, but it would be good to understand how it works.  It is simply an alias for `CF_SQL_VARCHAR` making it pointless?  Does it always send strings as `nvarchar`?  If so, does `CF_SQL_VARCHAR` always send in `varchar`?

I would hope that for backward compatibility's sake it is implemented as such:

If `String Format` is enabled `CF_SQL_VARCHAR` and `CF_SQL_NVARCHAR` both map to `nvarchar`.

If `String Format` is disabled then `CF_SQL_VARCHAR` maps to `varchar` and `CF_SQL_NVARCHAR` maps to `nvarchar`.

This would mean any pre-CF10 sites can move to CF10 and work, with the same performance considerations pre-CF10.

New sites, or sites that rewrite all queries to match `CF_SQL_VARCHAR` and `CF_SQL_NVARCHAR` with the database design will not get the performance penalty that is unavoidable pre-CF10.

Can anyone confirm if this is the case; even better if with something official?

Comment: Is anyone else experiencing a new issue with this where CF_SQL_VARCHAR is mapped to nvarchar even with string_format off?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While you are waiting for something more official, I will throw in my $0.02 ...

I did some digging and based on my observations (with an MS SQL datasource) I believe that:

- `CF_SQL_NVARCHAR` is not just an alias for `CF_SQL_VARCHAR`. It maps to the newer [NVARCHAR jdbc type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#NVARCHAR), which lets you to handle unicode values at a more granular level.
- `CF_SQL_NVARCHAR` values are always treated as `nvarchar`
- The handling of `CF_SQL_VARCHAR` depends on the [`String Format`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms378857%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) setting, same as in previous versions.

**CF_SQL_NVARCHAR Test/Results:**

If you enable datasource logging, you can see the driver invokes the special [`setNString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) method whenever `CF_SQL_NVARCHAR` is used. So ultimately the value is sent to the database as `nvarchar`. (You can confirm this with a SQL Profiler)

```
    // Query
    SELECT  ID
    FROM    Test
    WHERE   NVarcharColumn = <cfqueryparam value="#form.value#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_nvarchar">

    // Log 
    spy(...)>> PreparedStatement[9].setNString(int parameterIndex, String value)

    // Profiler
    exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 nvarchar(4000)',N'SELECT  ID
            FROM    Test
            WHERE   NVarcharColumn = @P1 ',N'Стоял он, дум великих полн'
```

**CF_SQL_VARCHAR Test/Results:**

In the case of `CF_SQL_VARCHAR`, it is technically flagged as `varchar`. However, the `String Format` setting ultimately controls how it is handled by the database. When the setting is enabled, it is handled as `nvarchar`. When it is disabled, it is treated as `varchar`. Again, you can verify this with a SQL Profiler.

Bottom line, everything I have seen so far says you are right on target about the implementation.

```
    // Query
    SELECT  ID
    FROM    Test
    WHERE   PlainVarcharColumn = <cfqueryparam value="#form.value#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">

    // Log
    spy(..)>> PreparedStatement[8].setObject(int parameterIndex, Object x, int targetSqlType)
    spy(..)>> parameterIndex = 1
    spy(..)>> x = ????? ??, ??? ??????? ????
    spy(..)>> targetSqlType = 12  (ie CF_SQL_VARCHAR)

    // Profiler (Setting ENABLED)
    exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 nvarchar(4000)',N'SELECT  ID
            FROM    Test
            WHERE   PlainVarcharColumn = @P1 ',N'Стоял он, дум великих полн'

    // Profiler (Setting DIS-abled)
    exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 varchar(8000)',N'SELECT  ID
            FROM    Test
            WHERE   PlainVarcharColumn = @P1 ','????? ??, ??? ??????? ????'
```

Comment: "When the setting is enabled, it is handled as varchar. When it is disabled, it is treated as nvarchar." I presume you meant the opposite of that?

Comment: Yep. Thanks for pointing it out. I was just fixing it when I saw your comment.

Comment: @Leigh, how do you enable datasource logging on the driver?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who runs into this, try adding `sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false` to the db connection string in cf administrator.