# How does ColdFusion handle UTF-8(Multiple-Byte) support?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I want to make a ColdFusion(10) project to be global. It should support more languages,such as Japanese,Chinese,Spanish,etc. I searched on the Internet and found that it can be done easily by adding one line:

```
<cfprocessingDirective pageencoding="utf-8">
```

But it is supposed to add it in every cfc or cfms. I tried to add it in Application.cfc, but failed to display expected contents. So what can I do to support multiple languages?(utf-8)

Also, I need to think about the database part. I designed the db with strings as "nvarchar". So when I insert/set new values, I must add a 'N' before the values. Since it is an existing project, and there are thousands of written insert/set blocks. How can I add the 'N' in every existing statement efficiently?

```
update table 
set name = N 'name'
```

I really appreciate it if you say anything help.

Comment: You should be using parameters.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks for your correction. UTF-8 can be 1-4 bytes. But my question is mainly on how to handle it in ColdFusion. And what do you mean by parameters?

Comment: *what do you mean by parameters* You should be using `cfqueryparam` on all query parameters. It utilizes bind variables, which among other things, help protect against sql injection. For CF10, you use `cfsqltype="cf_sql_nvarchar"` rather than prepending an `N`. See also this question on the [`String Format` setting and backward compatilibity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802388/what-are-the-details-for-using-cf-sql-nvarchar-in-coldfusion-10).

Comment: @YuanhaiShi: Actually, UTF8 is 1 - 6 bytes. (for non-BMP characters)

Comment: @YuanhaiShi: *RE I tried to add it in Application.cfc*  It does not work that way. ["You must add it to each page that has a nondefault encoding."](http://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/internationalization/internationalization_cfmx/internationalization_cfmx3.html). I would also suggest reading a few articles on i18n first, to get an idea of what it entails. For examle: http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/i18n/

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for your comments. "cfqueryparam" is a good practice. I will use it instead of 'N'. Since there are thousands of existing parameters, is there a way to batch modify them to be cfqueryparam?

Comment: @YuanhaiShi unfortunately no, CFBuilder search and replace is your friend.

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for your link. I will read and study it.

Comment: @YuanhaiShi - These might also be helpful in identifying non-parameterized queries. [qpscanner.cfc](http://qpscanner.riaforge.org/)  and [Adding cfqueryparams to a Legacy Site Without Losing Your Hair](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2008/7/26/cfqueryparam-tips-for-adding).

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for the tools. They are very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CF side:

CFBuilder 2 or any decent text editor would insert UTF-8 [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for you and UTF-8 would work right away in CF.  If your text editor does not support inserting BOM, then like you said, use `<cfprocessingDirective>` (as last resort)

SQL side:

For CF10+, you can use `CF_SQL_NVARCHAR` in `<cfqueryparam>`. ref: [What are the details for using CF_SQL_NVARCHAR in ColdFusion 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802388/what-are-the-details-for-using-cf-sql-nvarchar-in-coldfusion-10)

For CF9 or below, when setting up the datasource in CF Admin, String Format -- **Enable High ASCII characters and Unicode for data sources configured for non-Latin characters**.

Then use of any `<cfqueryparam type='CF_SQL_VARCHAR'>` will be translated into `N'string'` by CF.  However, any index built on the varchar column will not be utilized in the prepared statement.

Comment: I am using CFBuilder 2. But How can it insert utf-8 BOM? automatically? Should I turn on something? I read similar instructions on the ColdFusion website, but I can not understand it.

Comment: I tried to create a new cfm file and output some Chinese characters. It can be displayed corrected. I looked at Properties of the cfm file. Found that BOM IS utf-8. But I found other existing cfms do not have this attribute. So how can I manually add "BOM" to them? Thanks.

Comment: CFBuilder or any Eclipse: Project Properties -> Resource -> Text file encoding: UTF-8

Comment: For existing CFM, u can open it in CFBuilder, change something and save.  BOM will be inserted.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. But I failed to get BOM inserted into existing cfm even I do change and save it in CFBuilder2.any ideas? The existing cfms were written in Dreamweaver.

Comment: Google for other tools that can insert BOM in batch for you.