# PreparedStatement.setNString(int,java.lang.String) error trying to use Query of Queries

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a simple Query of Queries statement like this:

```
<cfquery name="rsProductTypeID" dbtype="query">
SELECT
 ProductTypeID
FROM
 rsProductTypes
WHERE
 ProductType = <cfqueryparam value="Computers" cfsqltype="cf_sql_nvarchar"/>;
</cfquery>
```

All it is doing is asking for the primary key value (`ProductTypeID`) from the recordset `rsProductType` depending on which `ProductType` we are asking for.

For some reason the above query gives me this error:

```
PreparedStatement.setNString(int,java.lang.String)
```

But if I change the Query of Queries and remove the `<cfqueryparam>` part and replace it with normal text, then it works fine. Here is the working code:

```
<cfquery name="rsProductTypeID" dbtype="query">
    SELECT
     ProductTypeID
    FROM
     rsProductTypes
    WHERE
     ProductType = 'Computers';
 </cfquery>
```

I can't tell what the difference is between the code that is causing it to fail when using `<cfqueryparam>` and not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured it out... when ColdFusion returns a recordset, it doesn't maintain the original datatype from the database. In my database `ProductType` is defined as `nvarchar(50)` but ColdFusion returns it as `varchar` format. So the `cfsqltype` attribute was causing the error. I changed the cfsqltype attribute to `cf_sql_varchar` and it works fine. Very annoying but what can you do.

I posted it as a self-answer in case anyone else gets this error. Not sure if that's against the rules or not.

Comment: What did you change it from?  Your question shows cf_sql_varchar as the cfsqltype.  Semi-colons in cfquerys sometimes cause problems.  I suggest that you get in the habit of not using them.

Comment: I've also just learnt that the WHERE statement in a Query of Queries is case-sensitive. So `ProductType = 'computers'` matches nothing, but `ProductType = 'Computers'` returns a record.

Comment: where clauses are case sensitive almost everywhere except for sql server.

Comment: "Very annoying but what can you do." raise a bug with Adobe. And post the bug ref back here.

Comment: @AdamCameron not a bad idea but easier said than done. just been to http://cfbugs.adobe.com/ and it says site unavailable. not sure if its a permanent thing because it doesn't say when it will be back up. Oh how I wish Macromedia still existed.

Answer (score 2):

`cf_sql_nvarchar` is not a valid value for the `cfsqltype` attribute of `cfqueryparam`

Docs: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfqueryparam

Comment: Sean - That is a mistake in the documentation. It was added in CF10. The new type is a [more granular alternative to the old "String Format" setting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802388/what-are-the-details-for-using-cf-sql-nvarchar-in-coldfusion-10/10848136). That said, I do not know how it is handled with QoQ's.

Comment: Too bad we cannot edit the CF docs the way we can S.O. questions and answers ;-)

Comment: @AdamCameron - Not just leave comments like with the old docs? Huh, if so .. learn something new everyday.

Comment: You need to apply for a login, but if they gave one to me, they'll give one to anyone.