# CFQueryParam/cfsqltype for MS-SQL varchar(max) datatype

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I'm in the process of updating MS-SQL table structures to use nvarchar(max) instead of the text datatype.

Previously, for my ColdFusion queries using the text datatype, I used `cfsqltype="CF_SQL_LONGVARCHAR"`:

```
<cfquery name="local.qryUpdateByPK" datasource="#local.dsn#">
UPDATE
    [JobPosting]
SET
    [JobDescription] = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.JobDescription#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_LONGVARCHAR" null="#YesNoFormat(NOT Len(Trim(arguments.JobDescription)))#">
WHERE
    [JobPostingID] = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.JobPostingID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
</cfquery>
```

I'm wondering what should be used for the cfsqltype attribute when using nvarchar(max) or varchar(max).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If memory serves, information on the `nvarchar` support was a bit sketchy in the main Adobe documentation [last I checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802388/what-are-the-details-for-using-cf-sql-nvarchar-in-coldfusion-10). However, the correct sqltype for `nvarchar(max)` is `CF_SQL_LONGNVARCHAR`.

**Update:**

The new types are mentioned *briefly* in [Database Enhancements for CF10](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e02b-7ff3.html#WSe61e35da8d318518-9efe7cf1358680a71d-8000)

> **New data type support for CFSQLType**
>
> The cfqueryparam and cfprocparam tags support the following SQL types:
>
> - CF_SQL_NCHAR
> - CF_SQL_NVARCHAR
> - **CF_SQL_LONGNVARCHAR**
> - CF_SQL_NCLOB
> - CF_SQL_SQLXML